# CSRF token mismatch in cakephp3.7

Tags: php, postgresql, mysqli, cakephp-3.0

I am create one survey form for that i create one controller manually under one method weblink that list all the question on the screen with form.

when i click on submit button i call add method in the same controller with from request data but it gives error.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\User[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface 
  paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class SurveyquestionController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter($event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
       // Allow users to register and logout.
       // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
       // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
       $this->Auth->allow(['webink']);
   }
   /**
    * webink method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
 */
public function webink()
{
    $this->loadModel ('Questionmaster');
    $questions = $this->Questionmaster->find('all')->contain(['Questiontype']);
    $this->set(compact('questions'));
}

/**
 * Add method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
public function add()
{
    print_r($this->request->getData());
    die;
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}



}
```

AppController

```
<?php
```

/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

```
/**
 * Initialization hook method.
 *
 * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
 *
 * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');


    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [

        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],

        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Survey',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],

        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'                
        ],
        //use isAuthorized in Controllers
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()


    ]);
    /*
     * Enable the following component for recommended CakePHP security settings.
     * see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html
     */
    //$this->loadComponent('Security');

}


public function beforeFilter($event) {

    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'logout']);

}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you can see in the stacktrace, the error stems from the [**CSRF middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware). Do not use both, the CSRF middleware and the [**CSRF component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html), that won't work. Disable the component, it's deprecated anyways.